# How to use the window.location.assign with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use the `window.location.assign` to change my project page, but it's not working.
The page I want to change is in the same folder.

My Code:

```js
filterFunc (){
   window.location.assign("/teste");  
}
```

> Failed to load https://console.bluemix.net/analytics/bmaid: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> index.js:2178 +++DBDM-ERROR > getAnonymousID > Ajax call error. (Execution time: 309ms):

In the IDE it does not error, only on the page after clicking the button.

If someone has an idea of how to do it? Switch pages by clicking the button!

Comment: Could you use router BrowserRouter and redirect?

Comment: If you want to use assign method, you should pass URL as parameter instead of relative path Check Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign

Comment: you can also try `window.location.href`

Answer (score 1):

The location.assign should work you are using the right methode only to need to change one thing

```
window.location.assign("/teste");
```

should be

```
window.location.assign("http://localhost:3000/teste");
```

this is also the way w3schools does it. But what I sad you're are on the right path.

**Note:** It is best practice to use window.location, this is supported by most browsers, eg: `window.location = 'http://google.com'`

Comment: And also don't you use a extarnal package try to avoid that as much as possible. The more packages you use the more changed there are of you're application breaking with an update.